# VS code debugging ASP.NET + Chrome

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to configure VS code to debug seamlessly solutions with server code in ASP.NET Core and JS files in Chrome.

Something available in full VS (unfortunately only in IE).
I can put breakpoints on both JS files and CS files.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Anyone? I can't image it's not possible.

Comment: Same question, It's a shame

Answer (score 1):

Create one configuration for the ASP.NET Core application and another one for Chrome (you need the [Debugger for Chrome](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome) extension). Then create a [composite launch configuration](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/14842#issuecomment-262730707).

When you start debugging using the composite configuration you will be able to debug the ASP.NET code as well as the Javascript/Typescript code in the same Visual Studio Code instance. You can also launch each configuration manually and it should work.

Your `launch.json` file should look something like this (with an ASP.NET Core application called myapp):

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "compounds": [
        {
            "name": "Browser/Server",
            "configurations": [
                "Server",
                "Browser"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Server",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.1/myapp.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "env": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/Views": "${workspaceRoot}/Views"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Browser",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "url": "http://localhost:5000",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/wwwroot"
        },
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way :

1. Close IE but debuging are Running
2. Choose Lunch Chrome (must config lunch.json URL same )